# Instrumenting upon argument value

Tags: c++, instrumentation

In the project I'm working on, we agreed on using only functions returning error codes (no exceptions) to handle errors.

In order not to "pollute" my code with debug messages I was working on a solution based on instrumentation (inspired by [this post](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/)) .

Instead of using ints as the error code, I'm encapsulating it in a class as:

```
// File rc.h
class rc
{
public:
    rc(int) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
    rc& operator=(rc);
private:
    int value;
};
```

Then defining these operators and the instrumentation functions as:

```
// File rc.cc
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "rc.h"

static FILE *fp_trace;
static int isError;    

extern "C"
{

  void __attribute__ ((constructor)) trace_begin (void)
    {
      fp_trace = fopen("trace.out", "w");
      isError = 0;
    }

  void __attribute__ ((destructor)) trace_end (void)
    {
      if(fp_trace != NULL) {
        fclose(fp_trace);
      }
    }

  void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *func,  void *caller) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
  void __cyg_profile_func_exit (void *func, void *caller) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));

  void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *func,  void *caller)
  {
  }

  void __cyg_profile_func_exit (void *func, void *caller)
  {
    if ((fp_trace != NULL) && (isError == 1)) {
      fprintf(fp_trace, "x %p %p %lu\n", func, caller, time(NULL));
      isError = 0;
    }
  }
}

rc::rc(int valueIn) :
  value(valueIn)
{
}

rc& rc::operator=(rc rcIn)
{
  value = rcIn.value;
  if (value != 0)
  {
      isError = 1;
      fprintf(fp_trace, "%d\n", value);
  }
  return *this;
}
```

However, in order not to print too much things, I don't want to log function calls that returns return code 0 thus the `isError` flag.

This can be used with the following example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include "rc.h"

rc bar(void)
{
  rc result(std::rand() % 3);
  return result;
}

int main(void)
{
  std::srand (std::time(NULL));
  rc returnCode(0);
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
    returnCode = bar();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compile and run with

```
g++ -finstrument-functions -g -c -o rc.o rc.cc 
g++ -g -c -o test.o test.cc 
g++ test.o rc.o -o a.out 
./a.out
```

Reading the output with the script given [in the previously mentioned post](https://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/10/06/trace-and-profile-function-calls-with-gcc/) will result in something like:

```
Error code 2
rc::operator=(rc) at 2016-07-03T18:32:09+0200, called from main (test.cc:32)
```

This is almost what I could have wished. But compared with a solution where I would simply add a test in `rc foo(void)` to test whether the output is non zero and then log the error, that will add overhead only (plus the overhead due to the check) in the case where an error occurs (hopefully not too often), I am going to add overhead due to the instrumentation (plus the possible overhead due to the rc wrapper but I'm OK with it) at each call…

Is there a solution, that I couldn't thought off, that wouldn't instrument the `operator=` in the case where the argument is zero? Since `rc::value` is known only at runtime, I don't think a template with argument the value that would be specialized for `value=0` and wouldn't instrument that case would work. Would it?

There is an extra constraint: it is important the instrumented function is the assignment operator since I want to know the caller, hence I can't add some extra proxy level.

---

**edit** on this last point, I've thought of making the assignment operator inline (and not instrumented) and call an instrumented function in the case the return code isn't zero but that can't work as [finstrument-function doc page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) states that:

> This instrumentation is also done for functions expanded inline in other functions. The profiling calls will indicate where, conceptually, the inline function is entered and exited.

So that it wasn't pointing to the real caller.

Comment: You do know that  you'll likely end up with exceptions in your program anyway, unless you write all the code from scratch and never use any C++ libraries?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. But we are rewriting a lot of things…

Comment: A good hint is to use negative numbers as error codes, and positive values for results (0 included). That's what Linux system calls do.

Comment: This wouldn't let me choose not to instrument results though, would it? Anyway our constraints enforce us to use unsigned return code (which I do not reflect in the example)

Comment: What's the point of the instrumentation?  It seems you end up instrumenting your `rc` class, specifically the exit of its `operator=`.  What's the point in that?  Did you mean to instrument the function call whose result was assigned using that `operator=`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck The point of the instrumentation is to follow any function call that would return a non null return code without having to write specific code for them but only using the instrumentation. Maybe it's not the best way to follow them. By instrumenting only the `rc` class, I instrument only a small part of my code. But since all function return `rc` instances, if I can't turn off instrumentation when `rc` is null, I have about the same overhead…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution isn't to rely on instrumentation but on the `__builtin_return_address(unsigned int)` function that is used by instrumentation.

You can use this function to get the return pointer of the caller:

```
rc& rc::operator=(rc rcIn)
{
  value = rcIn.value;
  if (value != 0)
  {
      fprintf(fp_trace, "%d %p\n", value, __builtin_return_address(1));
  }
  return *this;
}
```

That way you don't need to rely on instrumentation to get the caller address and will add a really little overhead over using simply an int.